# preventing adds of KVPs with duplicate key Values c#

Tags: c#, list, duplicates, key, keyvaluepair

I have a list of (int,int) KeyValuePairs and I want to prevent adds to this is if the key already exists. Is this function already present? or do I have to prevent the add in some other way?

EDIT: Additionally I want to be able to sort the collection by the value in ascending order. Is there a way to do that as well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can simply use a Dictionary for such a thing and I guess you have used KeyValuePair mistakenly

Comment: oh forgot to mention this is a <int, int> kvp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `List<>` of `KeyValuePair` best approach would be to use a `Dictionary`, which is also a key value pair collection but with additional members.

**[Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :**

> Represents a collection of keys and values.

In your case you could simply use `Dictionary<int,int>` , which means a dictionary with `int` key and `int` value.

**Key uniqueness**

> Every key in a Dictionary must be unique according to the dictionary's equality comparer

When adding data simply use `Dictionary.ContainsKey` [Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx) which would return a `Boolean` value to indicate Key existence.

[**ContainsKey Method :**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Determines whether the Dictionary contains the specified key.

Hope you would go thorough documents and fulfill  the requirement.

**Additional:**  for sorting ,, using `LINQ` would be easy ([Source](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sort-dictionary))

```
// dictionary is our Dictionary<int,int>
var items = from pair in dictionary orderby pair.Value ascending select pair; 

// Display results.
 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in items)
 { 
      Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
 }
```

Comment: oh hm i glazed over the fact i could use a dictionary... I'm still new to c# haha. Thanks for that >.<

Comment: @xglide No problem,, hope you get the right answer :) mark it correct if it solves your problem or is the best solution

Comment: i forgot i had wanted to sort the collection by their values in ascending order. In hindsight I should have added that as well in the question. I've edited it to reflect that now.

Comment: Simply use Linq : var items = from pair in dictionary
      orderby pair.Value ascending
      select pair;

 // Display results.
 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in items)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
 }

Comment: could you edit that into your post for formatting. I'm having trouble reading it. Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're not using Dictionary?

For using normal List and KeyValuePair you can use the below code

//inside a function

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in myList)  
   if (kvp.Key == key)  
        return;  
myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(key, value));
```

**EDIT :** 
When using Dictionary you can use the below code

```
var items = from pair in dictionary
            orderby pair.Value ascending
            select pair;
```

Comment: I forgot about dictionaries. I'm still new to c# thanks much tho haha

Comment: Oh i forgot. The reason is because I want to be able to sort by the Value. Is there a way to do that with dictionaries

Comment: @xglide Yes you can, Check Extension methods in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx